# Instance method 'setValue(forKey:to:)' requires that 'TravelMode' conform to 'PersistentModel'

Tags: swift, swift-data

I modified a model within my code changing a field from type `Int` to an enum value type `ModelType`.

Since doing this my app will not build! I get the message:

> /var/folders/x1/pptzf9797576q9pzdzvr2qqh0000gn/T/swift-generated-sources/@__swiftmacro_7TripApp7JourneyC10travelMode18_PersistedPropertyfMa_.swift:4:23 Instance method 'setValue(forKey:to:)' requires that 'TravelMode' conform to 'PersistentModel'

What have I done wrong? I followed one of the several examples that are available.

The model is:

```swift
enum TravelMode: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case undefined, flight, car, train, hike, sail, other
    var id: Self { self }
}

@Model
class Journey: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var trip: String
    var name: String
    var date: Date
    var latitudeFrom: Double
    var longitudeFrom: Double
    var latitudeTo: Double
    var longitudeTo: Double
    var travelMode: TravelMode?
    var details: String
```

It is used as follows when assigning the value:

```
travelMode: .flight,
```

and its associated picker lookalike:

```swift
Picker("Travel Mode", selection: $selectedTravelMode) {
    ForEach(TravelMode.allCases) { travelMode in
        Text(travelMode.rawValue.capitalized)
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add Codable to the enum

Comment: I resolved this problem by following the example given in "SwiftData Mastery".   The enum was changed to:

Comment: enum TravelMode: String, Codable, CaseIterable {
        case undefined = "Undefined"
        case flight = "Flight"
        case car = "Car"
        case train = "Train"
        case hike = "Hike/On Foot"
        case sail = "Sail/Ferry"
        case other = "Other"

Comment: and the Picker to:

Comment: Picker("Travel Mode", selection: $journey.travelMode) {
                    ForEach(Journey.TravelMode.allCases, id: \.self) { travelMode in
                        Text(travelMode.rawValue)
                            .tag(travelMode)
                    }
                }

Comment: If you have a solution then post it as an answer since it’s fine to answer your own question. Code posted in the comments section is always hard to read and the solution might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Your enum must conform to `Codable` in order for it to conform to `PersistentModel`

```
enum TravelMode: String, Codable, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case undefined, flight, car, train, hike, sail, other
    var id: Self { self }
}
```